# Use two composer autoloaders in phing to run phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, phing, autoloader

I have a situation, that all app code comes from one source already compiled and in read only access. I need to run tests, but code that comes to me do not have phpunit installed.

Would it be possible to pass 2 autoloaders to phpunit using phing? One with app dependencies and other with phpunit?

Answer (score -1):

`phpunit` is a command line program that already comes with it's own autoloading, and it only needs the directory with test classes (applying it's own autodetection/autoloading to them), and a bootstrap script which allows to instantiate all the classes that at some point need to be tested.

So the answer is "yes, expect to be able to use two autoloaders", but there most certainly is no need to fiddle with the autoloader coming with PHPUnit.